# Linux-based network backup solution

Tags: linux, networking, backup, open-source

Do you have any recommendations for a Linux based backup solution that would be capable of backing up MS Servers and servers hosting MS Exchange data? I've started doing my own research, but so far have come up with few options. I'd prefer something open-source. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

On the Ubuntu side Canonical suggests http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

[www.bacula.org](http://www.bacula.org)

Answer (score 2):

Amanda.org too.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fairly happy with [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) for disc-to-disc backups (as opposed to going to tape).  It provides a nice web interface for managing it, and works very well for smaller groups of backups, say 10 or 20 machines.